# How to find navcontroller with view binding?

Tags: java, android, android-navigation, android-navigationview

I am using view binding in my app.
But now I am facing issue with finding navcontroller with view binding.

If I use traditional way to set content view with layout, I can easily find navcontroller with this piece of code.

```
Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment)
```

But if I use view binding to set content view how can I find navcontroller since the above code requires ID of navHostFragment but view bending returns fragment if I give `binding.navHostFragment`

Comment: it's the same line, it shouldn't be different and you should be still using this line of code, what's wrong with `Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ViewBinding`, As its name implies, is used to bind views not to bind **resource identifiers**.

What `ViewBinding` offers you in its simple form, that you don't have to `findViewById(view_id)` anymore; instead it offers `binding.myView`.. Both cases **returns a view.**

But in the `NavController` context, you don't have to get a view (but a resource id), so that view binding won't benefit you (again because it binds views not ids).

So, you will have to use the same code to get the `NavController`:

```
Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment)
```

Comment: before I get error but now it's working. May be I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Fist thing you have to use **FragmentContainerView** instead of **fragment**
don't forget to use the same name attribute and  that's it! now you can find it in the binding elements

so as example you have to change this :

```
        <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mainFragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />
```

into this :

```
        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainerView"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation"
        />
```